# How to delete lines form multiple text files at once in command line?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed, text

I've been trying to delete the second and third lines from about 50 text files.

I need to keep the headers but delete lines "1" and "2", meaning I need to delete the second and third lines of each text file. I have been trying to use:

sed -i.bak '2,3d' *.txt

But in only deletes the lines from the first file in the folder. How can I get this to apply to all the files in the folder?

Comment: AFAIK that *should* have worked since the `-i` option implies the `-s` option, meaning that `2,3d` should have been applied to each file separately. However if you'd tested it *without* the `-i` (and without explicitly adding `-s`) you would have seen the changes applied only to the first file.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways, choice depends on how many files you have, how long the names are, and whether or not the filenames have "funny characters.

```
for i in *.txt ; do
    sed -i.bak '2,3d' "$i"
done
```

Or, the complex case:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -r -n 1 sed -i.bak '2,3d'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The first one worked like a charm!

Comment: Then please click the Accept checkmark.

Comment: Could you add explanations what these commands do? `sed` is capable of processing more than one file, so why not just `sed -i.bak 2,3d *.txt` or `find … -exec sed -i.bak 2,3d {} +` ?

Comment: The commands are explained in their `man` pages. `man bash`, `man sed`, `man find` and `man xargs`. I see no reason why I should re-document the commands.